# Item Details Page using angularjs $routeParams

Tags: angularjs, routeparams

I am building an online store with angularjs and I am having a hard time figuring out how to link to the details.html and have it display the specific items details. Currently when I click on the view more button url will show the name of the item. The only way i can get it to show is by making a link like this: #/details/:{{item.name}}. Everything I've read online says it should be #/details/:name but that returns :name in the url and not details/:Macbook Pro as an example. If I do it the correct way it redirects back to the home page. Here's my code so far.

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/about',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/computers',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/computers.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/smartphones',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/smartphones.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/tablets',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/tablets.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/details/:{{item.name}}',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).

        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'             
        });
    }]);

myApp.controller('storeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',  function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {


$scope.homeHeading = 'All Products';
$scope.aboutHeading = 'About Us';
$scope.computersHeading = 'Computers';
$scope.smartphonesHeading = 'Smartphones';
$scope.tabletsHeading = 'Tablets';

$http.get('js/products.json').then(function(result) {
    $scope.products = result.data;


});

$scope.minusOne = function(index) { 
    $scope.products[index].dislikes += 1; 
};
$scope.plusOne = function(index) { 
    $scope.products[index].likes += 1; 
};





}]);
```

computers.html

```
<div>
<h1>{{computersHeading}}</h1>

<div class="product col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in products | filter:search   | filter:'Laptop'">
<img ng-src="{{ item.cover }}" >
<h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
<p class="price">{{ item.price }}</p>
<p class=""> <b>Storage</b>: {{ item.specs.storage }}</p>
<p> <b>Memory</b>: {{ item.specs.memory }}</p>

<!----- Save ratings for details page 
<div class="rating">
    <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    {{ item.likes }} </p>
    <p class="dislikes" ng-click="minusOne($index)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> {{ item.dislikes }} </p>

</div> -->
<a href="#/details/:{{item.name}}" class="btn btn-custom"> View Product</a>

</div>

</div>
```

Again the only way to get the item name to show in the url is to have the brackets in the url and i know that is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, I needed to make a controller for the details page and then get the json data. I then changed my href link to

```
<a href="#/details/{{products.indexOf(item)}}" class="btn btn-custom"> View Product</a>
```